# HTTP GET redirect not working

Tags: php, http, get, urlencode

I have a page that receives data passed from a form. It doesnt properly redirect with all the variables passed. I think its because there are spaces in the data passed so the URL breaks at the space. I tried to do a urlencode but I couldnt get it to work properly. I am thinking I need to urlencode the variables been passed with spaces in them but I need your help.

Here's the code:

```
<?
$aff = $_GET['aff'] ;
$click_id = $_GET['click_id'] ;
$email = $_GET['from'];
$fname = $_GET['name_(awf_first)'];
$lname = $_GET['name_(awf_last)'];
$zipcode = $_GET['custom_zipcode'];
$address = $_GET['custom_address'];
$phone = $_GET['custom_phone_no'];
$state = $_GET['custom_state'];
$city = $_GET['custom_city'];
$subid = $_GET['meta_adtracking'] ;
$cblink = $_GET['cblink'];
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'] ;
$keyword = eregi_replace('[^a-z0-9 ]', '2', $keyword);
?>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT=0;URL="http://mywebsite.com/page/?pID=sample&email=<?print $email?>&fname=<?print $fname?>&lname=<?print $lname?>&addr=<?print $address?>&city=<?print $city?>&state=<?print $state?>&zip=<?print $zipcode?>&hphone=<?print $phone?>&mphone=<?print $phone?>&country=US&pubSubID=<?print $subid?>&destURL=http://mywebsite.com/page/testpage.php?pubSubID=[pubSubID]&email=[email]">
<html>
<body>
</body></html>
```

Comment: please always tag questions with the programming language you are using, or a more specific tag, to avoid wasting people's valuable time

Comment: Please add the code inline not as external image..

Comment: i am sorry about that i dont know how to add the code inline

Comment: Here you can read all about how to format your question: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');

?>
The above example will output:
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
foo=bar&amp;baz=boom&amp;cow=milk&amp;php=hypertext+processor
```

---

for your case

```
$get_data=$_GET;
echo http_build_query($get_data) . "\n";
echo http_build_query($get_data, '', '&amp;');
```

Comment: +1 I'm not sure about your mistake, if any, but http_build_query() is useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues that need to be addressed heres:

1. Accessing indices of arrays whose existence is not verified: PHP throws an error if you try to read a variable that does not exist. You should use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) or [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) (in case of an array) before reading that variable, e.g.:

   ```
    if (isset($_GET['aff'])) {
        $aff = $_GET['aff'];
    } else {
        $aff = null;
    }
   ```

You can also use the [conditional operator `?:`](http://php.net/language.operators) for a shorter variant of this:

```
    $aff = isset($_GET['aff']) ? $_GET['aff'] : null;
```

2. You need to use proper encoding on the URL parameter values: either use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) to encode the value according to the [*application/x-www-form-urnelcoded* content type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) or [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) for the plain [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) or – as you build the entire query – [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query):

   ```
    $query = array(
        'pID' => 'sample',
        'email' => isset($_GET['from']) ? $_GET['from'] : null,
        'fname' => isset($_GET['name_(awf_first)']) ? $_GET['name_(awf_first)'] : null,
        'lname' => isset($_GET['name_(awf_last)']) ? $_GET['name_(awf_last)'] : null,
        'addr' => isset($_GET['custom_address']) ? $_GET['custom_address'] : null,
        'city' => isset($_GET['custom_city']) ? $_GET['custom_city'] : null,
        'state' => isset($_GET['custom_state']) ? $_GET['custom_state'] : null,
        'zip' => isset($_GET['custom_zipcode']) ? $_GET['custom_zipcode'] : null,
        'hphone' => isset($_GET['custom_phone_no']) ? $_GET['custom_phone_no'] : null,
        'mphone' => isset($_GET['custom_phone_no']) ? $_GET['custom_phone_no'] : null,
        'country' => 'US',
        'pubSubID' => isset($_GET['meta_adtracking']) ? $_GET['meta_adtracking'] : null,
        'destURL' => 'http://mywebsite.com/page/testpage.php?pubSubID=[pubSubID]&email=[email]'
    );
    $query = http_build_query($query);
   ```
3. You need to use proper encoding on the HTML attribute value; use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

   ```
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('0;URL=http://mywebsite.com/page/?'.$query); ?>">
   ```

Comment: can you show me a full sample of how the page should be edited to look like with the code provided

Comment: @artur: You can take the second-last and last code fragment to get the desired result.

Comment: i seem to have made a mistake somewhere as it came up with an error.

Warning: Unexpected character in input: ''' (ASCII=39) state=1 in /home/thanks.php on line 19

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in /home/thanks.php on line 19

Comment: can you look at the code edits I made and tell me where i made a mistake. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urlencode) all values. In particular the URL that you pass as a value of the `destURL` param. You can convert the URL just once (e.g., try [this online tool](http://www.string-functions.com/urlencode.aspx)), since it seems to be static in your code:

```
...&destURL= http%3a%2f%2fmywebsite.com%2fpage%2ftestpage.php%3fpubSubID%3d%5bpubSubID%5d%26email%3d%5bemail%5d
```

Comment: The redirect happens after the user submits the form its the spaces in the data submitted thats causing a break in the url and so all the data is not passed. I know I need to url encode all the GET variables but I cant do it correctly

Comment: From your original question I didn't figure it was PHP. So somebody else has to answer how to do URL encode in PHP... :p